# Apache Pool 2 library - connections not closed automatically

Tags: scala, olap4j, apache-commons-pool

I have the following code in Scala that uses the Apache `pool2` library. The object to pool is `OlapConnection` (an `olap4j` class, similar to an SQL connection).

Problem is that I can't make the pool close the connections *automatically* when the number of pooled objects exceeds the maximum.

If I return an object to the pool (with `pool.returnObject`) that triggers `passivateObject`. If I close the connection in `passivateObject`, I would close it every time I return an object, and that's not what I want - I need the open connections to be cached. If I *don't* close the connection in `passivateObject`, then it will never be closed.

How to make this work?

Scala code:

```
class OlapConnectionUtil (val pool: ObjectPool[OlapConnection]) {
     def connect = {
        pool.borrowObject
     }
     def close(olapConnection: OlapConnection) = {
       pool.returnObject(olapConnection)
     }
}

class OlapConnectionFactory extends BasePooledObjectFactory[OlapConnection] {

  override def create = {           
      val connectionString = "jdbc:mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foodmart?" + 
            "user=x&password=x;Catalog=FoodMart.xml;JdbcDrivers=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"           
       val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString)
       connection.unwrap(classOf[OlapConnection])
    }

    override def wrap(olapConnection: OlapConnection) = 
                                  new DefaultPooledObject(olapConnection)

    override def passivateObject(pooledObject: PooledObject[OlapConnection] ) {
      println("passivateObject WAS CALLED")
      pooledObject.getObject.close
    }    

  }


class Test  {

  val olapConnectionFactory = new OlapConnectionFactory

  def test = { 

     val config = new GenericObjectPoolConfig
     config.setMaxIdle(5)
     config.setMaxTotal(10)

     val util = new OlapConnectionUtil(
                 new GenericObjectPool[OlapConnection](olapConnectionFactory,config))
     val olapConnection = util.connect

     // do stuff with olapConnection

     util.close(olapConnection)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the JavaDocs for [`PooledObjectFactory`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/api-2.5.0/org/apache/commons/pool2/PooledObjectFactory.html) you may see that

> 4. `passivateObject(org.apache.commons.pool2.PooledObject<T>)` is invoked on every instance when it is returned to the pool.
> 5. `destroyObject(org.apache.commons.pool2.PooledObject<T>)` is invoked on every instance when it is being "dropped" from the pool (whether due to the response from `validateObject(org.apache.commons.pool2.PooledObject<T>)`, or for reasons specific to the pool implementation.) There is no guarantee that the instance being destroyed will be considered active, passive or in a generally consistent state.

In other words you should put your resource de-allocation logic into the **`destroyObject`**. Here is a modified test of yours with a fake `OlapConnection` implementation

```
import org.apache.commons.pool2._
import org.apache.commons.pool2.impl._

// fake!
case class OlapConnection(val id: Int) {


  def close(): Unit = {
    println(s"Close was called for $this")
  }
}

class OlapConnectionUtil(val pool: ObjectPool[OlapConnection]) {
  def connect = {
    pool.borrowObject
  }

  def close(olapConnection: OlapConnection) = {
    pool.returnObject(olapConnection)
  }
}

class OlapConnectionFactory extends BasePooledObjectFactory[OlapConnection] {
  var cnt = 0

  override def create = {
    cnt += 1
    new OlapConnection(cnt)
  }

  override def wrap(olapConnection: OlapConnection) =
    new DefaultPooledObject(olapConnection)

  override def passivateObject(pooledObject: PooledObject[OlapConnection]) {
    println("-passivateObject was called")
  }

  override def destroyObject(pooledObject: PooledObject[OlapConnection]): Unit = {
    super.destroyObject(pooledObject)
    println("--destroyObject was called")
    pooledObject.getObject.close
  }
}

object Test {

  val olapConnectionFactory = new OlapConnectionFactory

  def test = {

    val config = new GenericObjectPoolConfig
    config.setMaxIdle(5)
    config.setMaxTotal(10)

    val util = new OlapConnectionUtil(new GenericObjectPool[OlapConnection](olapConnectionFactory, config))
    val initConnections = (1 to 10).map(i => util.connect).toList
    val closeCons = initConnections
    Thread.sleep(100)
    println("Start closing")
    closeCons.zipWithIndex.foreach(ci => {
      Thread.sleep(100)
      println(s"Before close ${ci._2 + 1}")
      util.close(ci._1)
      println(s"After close ${ci._2 + 1}")
    })
  }
}
```

The output produced by this code is:

> Before close 1
>   
>  -passivateObject was called
>   
>  After close 1
>   
>  Before close 2
>   
>  -passivateObject was called
>   
>  After close 2
>   
>  Before close 3
>   
>  -passivateObject was called
>   
>  After close 3
>   
>  Before close 4
>   
>  -passivateObject was called
>   
>  After close 4
>   
>  Before close 5
>   
>  -passivateObject was called
>   
>  After close 5
>   
>  Before close 6
>   
>  -passivateObject was called
>   
>  --destroyObject was called
>   
>  Close was called for OlapConnection(6)
>   
>  After close 6
>   
>  Before close 7
>   
>  -passivateObject was called
>   
>  --destroyObject was called
>   
>  Close was called for OlapConnection(7)
>   
>  After close 7
>   
>  Before close 8
>   
>  -passivateObject was called
>   
>  --destroyObject was called
>   
>  Close was called for OlapConnection(8)
>   
>  After close 8
>   
>  Before close 9
>   
>  -passivateObject was called
>   
>  --destroyObject was called
>   
>  Close was called for OlapConnection(9)
>   
>  After close 9
>   
>  Before close 10
>   
>  -passivateObject was called
>   
>  --destroyObject was called
>   
>  Close was called for OlapConnection(10)
>   
>  After close 10

As you can see in this output `close` is being called since `OlapConnection(6)` as one would expect given the pool configuration.

Comment: In the `create` method of `OlapConnectionFactory` you are instantiating a new object with `new OlapConnection`, instead I need to retrieve an existing connection from the pool, how do I do that?

Comment: @peterSc, You might see that in my example I use a **_fake_** class instead of the real `OlapConnectionFactory` because I don't want to set up all the real infrastructure which is unrelated to how to use the pool properly.